# Express and sinon: app.use callback function testing

Tags: unit-testing, express, mocha.js, sinon

I am wondering how to test this Express snippet:

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
        log.debug(`${MODULE_NAME}:ErrorHandler (ERROR) --> err: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
        res.status(err.status).json(err);
      });
```

using Sinon and Mocha. I've surfed all the Internet but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Here is the unit test solution:

`index.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');

const log = {
  debug: console.log,
};

function createServer() {
  const app = express();
  const MODULE_NAME = 'main';
  app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    log.debug(`${MODULE_NAME}:ErrorHandler (ERROR) --> err: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
    res.status(err.status).json(err);
  });
}

module.exports = createServer;
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const sinon = require('sinon');
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');

describe('60206259', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const mRes = { status: sinon.stub().returnsThis(), json: sinon.stub() };
    const mError = new Error('network');
    mError.status = 500;
    const appStub = { use: sinon.stub().callsFake((mw) => mw(mError, {}, mRes)) };
    const expressStub = sinon.stub().callsFake(() => appStub);
    const createServer = proxyquire('./', {
      express: expressStub,
    });

    createServer();
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(expressStub);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(appStub.use, sinon.match.func);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(mRes.status, 500);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(mRes.status().json, mError);
  });
});
```

Unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
60206259
main:ErrorHandler (ERROR) --> err: {"status":500}
    ✓ should pass (2802ms)


  1 passing (3s)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/60206259